# DOMTokenList.toggle: The token can not contain whitespace

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add classes to my element with this code:

```js
menu.classList.toggle('fa fa-times');
navbar.classList.toggle('active');
```

I'm getting an error because there should not be a space between the class names:

> error: DOMTokenList.toggle: The token can not contain whitespace.

But I want to use this class. What is the solution? I added the classes separately, but it didn't work

Comment: "*Because there should not be a space between the class name*" it's two class names. There isn't a class name with a space.

Comment: Add toggle for each class `menu.classList.toggle('fa'); menu.classList.toggle('fa-times');`.